# How to reference a div from inside of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, iframe, reference

So i have this type of structure:

```
<div id="status"></div>

<div id="main">
       <iframe src="something" id="myframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

I want to click something inside a frame and have a jquery call affect the 'status' div. Where would I place this Jquery call `$('#status').css('background', 'red')` .
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#status', window.parent.document).css('background', 'red')
```

Try that

Comment: You can PayPal me some cash :)